# CUDA: pointer to pointer memory access

Tags: cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation, access-violation, pointer-to-pointer

I can't figure out what is causing the issue. I get "access violation writing location" error in the last line. Am I not correctly allocating the memory?

```
    typedef struct {
    doubleXYZW cen_sum; //struct with 4 doubles
    double STS[6];
    XYZW *Points;// //struct with 4 floats
}BUNDLE;

BUNDLE *cpu_data = NULL;
size_t bundle_size = NUM_POINTS * sizeof(XYZW) + sizeof(doubleXYZW) + 6*sizeof(double);
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMallocHost((BUNDLE**)&cpu_data, bundle_size));
//error in the next line
cpu_data->Points[0].x = 0; //x is the first element in the XYZW struct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 allocations that must be done, and you are only performing one of them.

You are allocating some storage for the `cpu_data` pointer, but you have not allocated any storage for the `Points` pointer.  Therefore when you dereference Points:

```
cpu_data->Points[0].x = 0;
         ^      ^
         |      this dereferences the Points pointer (NOT allocated!)
         |
        this dereferences the cpu_data pointer (allocated)
```

you are dereferencing a pointer that you have not allocated, so it is invalid.  Attempting to access something that way will generate an invalid access.

You have (at least) two options to fix it:

1. after you have allocated space for `cpu_points`, you can perform another `cudaMallocHost` allocation on `cpu_points->Points`
2. If you know the size of the `Points` array (it seems like you do - `NUM_POINTS`) then you could just statically allocate for it:

   ```
   typedef struct {
   doubleXYZW cen_sum; //struct with 4 doubles
   double STS[6];
   XYZW Points[NUM_POINTS];// //struct with 4 floats
   }BUNDLE;
   ```

Note that your `bundle_size` calculation is crafted in such a way that the 2nd method is suggested.  If you go with the first method, your `bundle_size` calculation is incorrect.  In any event, with either method, it's easier just to compute `bundle_size` as `sizeof(BUNDLE)`.

To be clear, there is nothing CUDA-specific here (the error would be present e.g. if you used `malloc` instead of `cudaMallocHost`).  The problem is rooted in basic C understanding, not CUDA.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed lesson. It makes sense. I, obviously, have not implemented this level of complexity in C so encountered it with CUDA. As you suggested, second option suits well, probably saves some allocation time too.